# POST model properties to controller without using hidden inputs?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to allow a user to review a beer.  Given the basic models:

```
public class User 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Beer 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BeerReview
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Beer { get; set; }
     public virtual User { get; set; }
     public string Review { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view model that I'm using as well:

```
public class BeerReviewViewModel
{
     public BeerReview Review { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

I have the following controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Review(int id)
{
     var beer = // get beer by Id
     BeerReviewViewModel model = new BeerReviewViewModel 
     {
          BeerReview = new BeerReview
          {
               Beer = beer.First()
          }
     };
     return View("Review", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(BeerReviewViewModel submission)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          // here is the problem
          int id = submission.Review.Beer.Id;
     }
}
```

In my view, I provide a simple form for a user to review a beer.  The view looks like:

```
@model MyNamespace.BeerReviewViewModel
<h2>Review Beer:  @Model.Review.Beer.Name</h2>

@{
     using(Html.BeginForm()){
          <div>
               @Html.TextAreaFor(b => b.Model.Review.Review)
          </div>
          <div>
               <input type="submit" value="Post Review" />
          </div>
     }
}
```

Obviously I'm not posting anything about the beer itself to the controller, so the Beer object in BeerReviewViewModel is always null.  I'm wondering if since I already have my Beer object on the view prior to form submit, if there's a way to tell the form to send along this data on the POST.  I've tried using Bind[Prefix="b"] on the controller with no luck.  I suppose I could always just add an int to the BeerReviewViewModel and send a hidden value of the beer Id from the view to the controller (or send a hidden value for every beer property).  But again, this still seems hack-ish to me.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model needs to be flattened. If you think about what that post data contains, you're looking at a series of key-value pairs that get encapsulated into a query string. You won't be able to have nested objects (unless your default ctor has the ability to build those nested objects).

Or you could write your own model binder, but I find that's solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Well, for a POST it'll be in the payload, but same difference